# How to configure DNS to join an Active Directory domain while maintaining internet access?

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-domain

I have two virtual machines both running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter on my workstation. The first, lets say LIGERSERV, is an already-configured Active Directory server with a Active Directory-integrated DNS server also running on it, like so:

[image: DNS server on my AD server]

I am trying to set up LIGERSERV-B as a Federation Server for my domain. In attempting to join this new server to my domain, liger-av.com, like this:

[image: Joining LIGERSERV-B to the liger-av.com domain]

I get the error "An active Directory Domain Controller for the domain "liger-av.com" could not be contacted." I believe this is because I have set Google's DNS in LIGERSERV-B's DNS settings (8.8.8.8) instead of the static IP of my own local DNS server running on LIGERSERV. But, if I use the IP of my local DNS server for LIGERSERV-B's DNS configuration, I would no longer be able to access the internet on LIGERSERV-B. So my question is, is there any way for me to point to my DNS server's IP for the purposes of joining the domain, while using a public DNS server for all other purposes? Thanks

Comment: Sure;  You just need to configure LIGERSERV's DNS to forward DNS requests or to recursively resolve them.

Comment: May I know what's the type of the virtual switch of the LIGERSERV and LIGERSERV-B

Comment: I'm using the default hyper-v switch, do I need to use something more specialized?